# How to put all php foreach output value in html tags?

Tags: javascript, php, html

suppose i have a html code like this:

```
        <div class="data">
            <div class="arrayvalue"> Value Here: </div>
        </div>
```

Now i have a php code like this:

```
 <?php
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow",....,"purple");

foreach ($colors as $value) {
  echo "$value <br>";
}
?>
```

I just want to store those array value in

```
<div class="arrayvalue"> Here: </div>
```

Something similar to this:

```
    <div class="data">
            <div class="numvalue">Blue</div>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <div class="numvalue">Pink</div>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <div class="numvalue">Red</div>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <div class="numvalue">Yellow</div>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <div class="numvalue">Blue</div>
        </div>
```

Also, the no of  div has to be increased as the array value is increasing
if possible then by using AJAX.
Any idea? plz help me through this.

Answer (score 1):

You can just echo it, if you like:

```
foreach ($colors as $value) { 
    echo '<div class="data"><div class="numvalue">'.$value.'</div></div>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreach loop

i hope you get your answer .

```
<?php $colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow",....,"purple");
 foreach($colors as $key => $value) { ?>
<div class="data">
       
        <div class="<?php echo $value; ?>"> <?php echo $value; ?> </div>
        
    </div>


<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <div class="data">
        <?php
        foreach ($colors as $value) {
        ?>
        <div class="arrayvalue"><?php echo $value; ?> </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: There should be a separate "data" div for each value. Check the requested output